# Creating 2D array with 0s and 1s

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to create a 2d array 4x5.  Each row takes in the number of the row so the first row will be all 0's, 2nd row all 1's etc..

```
int main (void)
{
  int A[4][5],i,j;
 // int B[10][8];


  for  (i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (j=0;j<5;j++){
    A[i][j]=0;
    printf("%i\n", A[i][j]);
    }   return 0;
  }
}
```

having issues looping each row to fill out the 0's,1's etc.. any ideas ?

Comment: Hint: you want to insert run number but you are inserting just '0'.

Comment: Due to the likely academic nature of this question, I take it a block-initializer is out of the question, because given the predefined fixed nature of your 4x5 matrix, you'll be hard pressed to beat the performance.

Comment: Do you want an array of `0`'s and `1`'s only?

Comment: Is one of your "issues" -- you say you have but you failed to list them in detail! -- that you only get a single row of numbers? If you properly indented your code, you could see where your `return` gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop needs modification:

```
for  (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        A[i][j]=i;  //---> Assign each element in i-th row the value of i
        printf("%d", A[i][j]);
    }  
    printf("\n");
}
```

Sample [output](http://ideone.com/NDbIlX). Also use `%d` for printing `int`s.

Comment: "d, i -- converts a signed decimal integer in the style [-]dddd." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf